# Share Application Thread Pool among Requests

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, share, threadpool

I have a Spring-based application with a REST Service that imports a CSV file, parses it's content and after some record-by-record processing stores the data (again record-by-record) to the database. Storing the data to the database is time consuming as the file can grow up to several thousand records.

Now i thought of multi-threading - delegating the processing and storing the data to the database to threads. *Good idea* i thought, but then i figured out: *wait - there can be several users importing files at the same time, so creating thread pools with several hundred theads per request is probably not a good idea*.

Is it possible to create a thread pool of say 1000 threads per application and share this thread pool among all requests reaching the application - yes it is. But how can i limit the number of threads being taken by each thread?

I want to limit the number of threads per application to not overload the servers and i want to limit the number of thread being taken by each request to not have one thread to consumes all available resources (threads in particular that case) and starve all other request that might come...

Any ideas, thoughts?

Comment: you can use Semaphore library  java.util.concurrent.Semaphore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use semaphores to limit the number of concurrent threads accessing a specific resource.`java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` In the following example, we will implement a simple login queue to limit number users in the system:

```
class LoginQueueUsingSemaphore {

    private Semaphore semaphore;

    public LoginQueueUsingSemaphore(int slotLimit) {
        semaphore = new Semaphore(slotLimit);
    }

    boolean tryLogin() {
        return semaphore.tryAcquire();
    }

    void logout() {
        semaphore.release();
    }

    int availableSlots() {
        return semaphore.availablePermits();
    }

}
```

Notice how we used the following methods:

> tryAcquire()

return true if a permit is available immediately and acquire it otherwise return false, but acquire() acquires a permit and blocking until one is available.

> release()

release a permit

> availablePermits()

return number of current permits available

PS: exemple using is from [site](https://www.baeldung.com/java-semaphore)

Answer (score 1):

**Rephrasing your problem**

This is quite a complex situation. I will try to rephrase it to see if I understand your desired behavior correctly.

You have several applications that may receive batches of updates to be made on a central database. These updates come in batches from CSV files and each batch can contain several thousand records. You want to process these updates in parallel but:

1. You want to limit the number of threads used by each application
2. You want to guarantee progress of individual batches if multiple batches are being processed in parallel

**A first proposal with a flaw**

To limit the number of threads used by each application, you could use something like a [fixed-size executor service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) for each application. By giving an appropriate size to the underlying thread pool of each ExecutorService, you can guarantee that a single application will not starve the others.

The individual records can then be submitted to the executor service as individual tasks. If there are multiple batches being processed by a single application, the individual records coming from these batches will be put into a single queue in the Executor service. Records coming from the various batches will interleave as they are mixed in the single queue of the executor service.

The problem with this solution is that it does not guarantee that all the batches are processed concurrently. Assume you have a pool of 4 threads to support the executor service. If a large batch of records is submitted to the executor service, all 4 threads will start processing these records. Now, if a second batch comes in, it will be added to the queue after the first batch, meaning that the 4 threads will process all the records of the first batch before processing the second. It is good because the 4 threads are kept busy all the time but this is not the behavior that you want. In this situation, you would like at least one thread of the pool to start processing the records of the second batch, correct ?

**A possible solution?**

I think you could implement something similar to the Fixed Thread Executor service that fits your particular problem. Here is what I would do.

You could create a pool of threads (hereinafter "worker threads") that process individual records coming from several queues. A queue corresponds to a batch of records. When a new batch needs to be processed, create a new queue and insert it into the ring of queues from which worker threads are taking records to process. Throw your records into it so that threads can process them at the other end, and remove the queue from the ring when your batch is finished (queue is empty and you have no more record to put into this batch). All the queues are kept in a ring such that each thread can follow the following routine:

1. processes a record from a queue
2. move to the next queue (say the queue on the right)
3. repeat from step 1

Using such a scheme, you can be sure that however many batches come and go, they will all make progress, even if there are more batches than there are threads to take care of them. The worker threads will also be able to focus on a single batch if there is only one currently being processed.

I would suggest you use something like [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) to manage your batches. Obviously there are many programming pitfalls in implementing such a mechanism.

- concurrent access to queue by a worker thread when the queue is being removed from the ring,
- what to do with the worker threads when there are no queues and no records to process),
- what do you do when a worker checks a queue for records but there are no records to process (skip to the next queue ?)
- when there is a single queue but all the records have been taken care of and workers are starving for work (blockingly wait on the queue for records to come? what if the batch is actually finished)

Given the complexity of your question, you seem quite experienced and I think you should be able to figure this out. If not I expect to see more questions from you on StackOverflow !

Comment: So you would suggest to implement a round-robin strategy... btw: it’s not several applications sharing this pool of threads but several equally weighted requests, but the situation is pretty much the same

Comment: Ah ! So there is a single apllication and multiple requests. In this case I am indeed suggesting a single (custom) pool of threads with a Round-Robin strategy to process the various batches.